# How to redirected to current page after processing the code and its result on other page?

Tags: php, redirect

I have Email Newsletter on the Common Footer file whch is displayed all ove the site, I have Email Newsletter section in footer.

Now I want the newsletter input email to be processed and and return to the same page from where news letter has been subscribed. Also I do not have the permission to redirect the form to footer.php.

Please suggest some idea to make it happen

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question to make it clearer what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have a footer on every page with a link like this: (correct me if I'm wrong)

```
<div id="footer">
    <a href="/newsletter/subscribe.php">Subscribe to newsletter</a>
</div>
```

Let's say you're on a page with url

```
/article/20100924
```

and you want to go back to that page after processing /newsletter/subscribe.php

As usual there are several possible answers to this.

If configured correctly there should be a $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable in the server array pointing back to the page where the click originated you could use that, and after processing the form simply put

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

at the end of /newsletter/subscribe.php

If you don't trust $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to be correct you could put the originating page into  the link url like this:

```
<a href="/newsletter/subscribe.php?backurl=%2Farticle%sF20100924">
    Subscribe to newsletter
</a>
```

Comment: grt I Used the Second Idea.. :)

Comment: and why should you trust $backurl?

Comment: @sathia You shouldn't really, because any script kiddie can change the backurl variable to be whatever. So at the very least an url parameter should be testet very rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

```
$prev_page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header("Location: $prev_page");
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks Brother Sathia, I have already tried with this... and it works